# Can't Pass Ajax Data into HTML Table

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax

I'm having trouble with how can I pass data to tables using ajax. It would be great if anybody could figure out where I am doing something wrong. thank you so much in advance.

Ajax success

```
  success: function(response){ 
    for(i = 0; i<response.list_reports.length;i++){
      console.log(response.list_reports[i])
      document.getElementById("paid_bys").innerHTML = response.list_reports[i]; // Error
    }
    $("#rports").modal('show');
    $("#rports").val(null).trigger("change");
  }
```

Console output

[image]

What I've tried my table (index):1519 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered base-style">
    <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Names</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr>
            <td><span id="paid_bys"></td> //display here
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>                
</table>
```

Comment: this is not related to django it is js and HTML change the title

Comment: Maybe the table is not rendered at the time of execution the the ajax call

Comment: can you also do a `console.log( document.getElementById("paid_bys") )`

Comment: document.getElementById("paid_bys") is null it is written in the error "TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null" @cagri

Comment: @cagri thanks for your response but It returns null since `paid_bys` does not have the value, the modal show after the execution of the ajax, the problem is how can I display result or list in my table?

Comment: When that ajax call is called, on button press? or on document load?

Comment: It doesn't print the value of `paid_bys`, but the element itself. So apparently that element doesn't exist when you're trying to set the value. Make sure your code runs after all page is loaded

Comment: @wetler after the buttons pressed

Comment: is the Table Tag written in your HTML file or it is added by JavaScript?

Comment: @wetler It's in the javascript   Actually my whole table looks like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrWP7.png) and I just want to display it on table those list comes from my javascript

Comment: try inspect element and check if that table is available in your html code search for "paid_bys".

Comment: if i am right ```<td><span id="paid_bys"></td> ```  as I know should have </span> as ```<td><span id="paid_bys"></span></td> ```

Comment: @Ruperto I don't know if it is necessary to used span to retrieve those list in javascript

Comment: the first accepted answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489492/create-html-table-out-of-object-array-in-javascript is similar to needed JS. i.e. HTML tags plus data will be generated by JS. 'i hope this helps

Comment: @Ruperto Great idea, but I have I tried like this  [image_query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlHa9.png) and my div [div tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQivg.png) but it only returns 'Name' value

Comment: @Donna Mae if only the 'Name' value is returned then the  ```response``` does not contain the needed values, right?

Comment: @Ruperto I tried putting console inside loop and response contain a values, Is there any wrong from my code?

Comment: @Donna Mae it is no easy to tell unless the code for the ajax call is also shown. Also ```document.getElementById("paid_bys").innerHTML = response.list_reports[i];``` would keep overwriting the same location. That same location is ```document.getElementById("paid_bys").innerHTML```